# FileSystem.CopyDirectory with UIOption.AllDialogs does not display a dialog from within a specific part of my program

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having a hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong. I use `FileSystem.CopyDirectory` so I can display a native copy dialog using `UIOption.AllDialogs`. In one part of my program, this works perfectly fine. In another part, it copies, but doesn't display the dialog at all.

This is the part that does not display a dialog:

```
 private void saveBackupButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FileSystem.CopyDirectory(SelectedProfile.FolderPath + saveFolderPath, SelectedProfile.FolderPath + backupSavePath + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yy HH.mm.ss"), UIOption.AllDialogs);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //stuff
        }
    }
```

The part that works fine is on another form, looks like this:

```
private void Copy()
    {
        try
        {
            FileSystem.CopyDirectory(strCopyFromPath, strCopyToPath, UIOption.AllDialogs, UICancelOption.ThrowException);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //stuff
        }
     }
```

I've tried making a new project in VS and just only having the top code executing from a click of a button, and it works fine everytime. But when I try it from the program, it doesn't display the dialog.

Comment: It's hard to tell because the dialog won't be show if the copy happens quickly.  Could be that one copy was fast and the other slow and thus showed progress?  Or, Are you swallowing an exception that could be alluding to a problem?

Comment: /facepalm of course! The part that showed the dialog copies a pretty big amount of stuff, while this part that doesn't is about 10-20 megabytes in size. I just added some junk to increase the size and it's now showing the dialog, too. That explains it, thanks!

Comment: take a look at this as well as do a google search on FileCopy Progress with C# http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36647/How-to-copy-files-in-C-with-a-customizable-progres || http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_25192431.html

Comment: can you not do the same using a ShellExecute command as well within C# it's very easy to do as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter Ritchie mentions, it looks like this method does not produce a dialog when the copy operation happens fast enough.